# LocationManager in iOS reallocating before calling delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa

I am using ARC and calling LocationManager to get latitude and longitude, however before even calling the delegates, the content is being deallocated. Anyone have come across this issue before? How can I resolve this issue if possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a property to hold the reference to your location manager:

```
@proerty (strong,nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

Then in the .m file when you allocate the location manager:

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
```

Comment: I was making that mistake, by not making a strong reference of my custom class of LocationManager. Thank you for pointing it out.